# Maven project will not build

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

My question is about project build by maven in Jenkins.
I have a maven project in jenkins. When I build it locally, it works fine, when I build it through jenkins I get an error.
The Maven settings in jenkins are equal to the settings I have locally.
I am clueless as to why I get this error.

The error:

```
New build name is '#11_origin/develop'
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf
maven-plugin:4.1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0_1 in http://adm-nexus-xxx.xxx.xxx/repository/maven-public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: karaf-assembly @ line 23, column 16
```

My POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>xx.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>karaf-xxx</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>karaf-assembly</packaging>
<name>karaf-xxx-feature</name>
<description>karaf-xxx details</description>
<repositories>
    <!-- Apache ServiceMix repository (for region) -->
    <repository>
        <id>apache.servicemix.7.0.1</id>
        <name>Apache ServiceMix M2 repository</name>
        <!--     <url>http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/m2-repo</url>-->
        <!--url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix/servicemix</url-->
        <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- OPS4J SNAPSHOT repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy</id>
        <name>OPS4J snapshot repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- Apache SNAPSHOT -->
    <repository>
        <id>apache.snapshots.deploy</id>
        <name>Apache snapshot repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Maven Central</id>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<!-- DEPENDENCIES -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
        <type>kar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/karaf/apache-camel/2.15.2/apache-camel-2.15.2-features.xml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.karaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-camel</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.3</version>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <type>xml</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
        <artifactId>hawtio-karaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core -->
    <!--<dependency><groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId><artifactId>camel-core</artifactId><version>2.19.3</version><classifier>features</classifier></dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <type>xml</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>enterprise</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <type>xml</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-karaf</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.0</version>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <type>xml</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <!--
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/deploy</outputDirectory><resourcesresources><resource><directory>src/main/resources/deploy</directory><filtering>false</filtering><includes><include>**/*</include></includes></resource><resource><directory>src/main/filtered-resources</directory><filtering>true</filtering><includes><include>**/*</include></includes></resource></resources>-->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.2</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <!--  
        <plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId><version>2.6</version><executions><execution><id>process-resources</id><goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals></execution></executions></plugin>-->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/deploy</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/deploy</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <installedBundles>
                    <!--installedBundle>mvn:commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6</installedBundle-->
                    <installedBundle>mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/5.15.0/xml/features</installedBundle>
                    <installedBundle>mvn:org.apache.activemq/artemis-features/RELEASE/xml/features</installedBundle>
                </installedBundles>
                <bootFeatures>
                    <feature>standard</feature>
                    <feature>config</feature>
                    <feature>package</feature>
                    <feature>kar</feature>
                    <feature>ssh</feature>
                    <feature>activemq-broker</feature>
                    <feature>activemq-client</feature>
                    <feature>management</feature>
                    <feature>camel</feature>
                    <feature>camel-base64</feature>
                    <feature>camel-cxf</feature>
                    <feature>camel-mail</feature>
                    <feature>camel-jms</feature>
                    <feature>hawtio</feature>
                    <!--feature>aries-blueprint</feature-->
                    <!--feature>shell</feature-->
                    <!--feature>shell-compat</feature-->
                    <feature>feature</feature>
                    <feature>jaas</feature>
                    <feature>bundle</feature>
                    <feature>deployer</feature>
                    <feature>diagnostic</feature>
                    <feature>feature</feature>
                    <feature>instance</feature>
                    <feature>log</feature>
                    <feature>package</feature>
                    <feature>service</feature>
                    <feature>system</feature>
                    <feature>aries-proxy</feature>
                    <feature>camel-core</feature>
                </bootFeatures>
                <installedFeatures>
                    <feature>war</feature>
                    <feature>jndi</feature>
                    <feature>jpa</feature>
                    <feature>openjpa</feature>
                    <feature>jdbc</feature>
                    <feature>jms</feature>
                    <feature>transaction</feature>
                    <feature>spring</feature>
                </installedFeatures>
                <javase>1.8</javase>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This is probably either a wrong `settings.xml` or a problem with proxy/firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The POM which you published even is not valid as XML.
e.g. where root "project" tag?

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't show the project close tag, but I did post it along in the code block

Comment: looks like an answer to me, it won't be able to build the POM because it's not valid XML and it's missing the closing project tag